# How do you copy Sql table from one database to another database with differ field names

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a database name "`EmpOld`" with a table name "`Employee`" and a database name "`EmpNew`" with a table name "`Employee`".

The table structures are identical on both database tables except for the names in the table.

Here is a definition of the tables:

Database "`EmpOld`" table name "`Employee`" has following field names:

```
int       e_id 
char(20)  e_fname 
char(25)  e_lname
```

Database "`EmpNew`" table "`Employee`" has following field names:

```
int       id 
char(20)  fname 
char(25)  lname
```

Notice, the only difference in the tables is the "`e_`" prefix for field names are removed from the EmpNew Employee table.

How do I move data from `EmpOld` database to `EmpNew` database?

Is there a code that maps these field respectively.

Thanks community,

Nick

Answer (score 3):

Well, you could just name them manually:

```
INSERT dbo.EmpNew(fname, lname) SELECT e_fname, e_lname FROM dbo.EmpOld;
```

If you want to do this without manually typing out the column names, there is magic in SSMS - just drag the `Columns` folder from each table into the appropriate spot in your query window (and then manually remove identity columns, timestamp, computed columns etc. if relevant).

> [image]
>
> [image]

Comment: I suppose the above statement would work. Sorry for asking following (all my dba's left so I'm not a big sql guy), but is there a way to create field list and insert it into the above insert statement. My table in reality has 100 field names.  For example is can I do INSERT dbo.EmpNew( pre-generated fieldlist name) Select newfieldlistnames FROM dbo.EmpOld.

Comment: In Object Explorer, drag the `Columns` folder onto your query window. Makes laziness cool again. [See a visualization here](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic way of mapping fields, unless with some code.

This can be done in two ways:

1. Using the SQL Import & Export Wizard

   This is the most easy way to do this and [here is an article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/203/simple-way-to-import-data-into-sql-server/) that gives step by step to do this. The key is to change the mapping between the source and destination fields while importing the data.
2. Writing an SQL

   This method requires both the databases to be accessible. Using a simple insert statement as follows this can be achieved

   ```
   insert into EmpNew.dbo.Employee(id, fname, lname)
   select 
      e_id, e_fname, e_lname
   from
      EmpOld.dbo.Employee
   ```

   If they are on same sql server then the above will work good as is. If they are different sql server you may have to add a link server connection and prefix the table commands with that.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into your awesome solution.  By the way, any ideas on how I could remove the prefix "e_" in field names programmatically?  Both my database tables are identical.  I need to remove the prefix "e_" on all my fields on the database "EmpNew" employee table.  Any crazy code for that?  thanks again for all your help

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a code that maps these field respectively.

No - you'll need to provide the mapping.  If you're using an ETL tool like SSIS there *may* be a way to programatically map columns based on some criteria, but nothing built into SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can generate code with help from the tables [sys.columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms176106.aspx) and other system tables so that you can make the copy-process run automatically.

I think you can't use:

```
insert into (...) (...)
```

because you have two databases. So just generate insert statements like:

```
insert into table (...) VALUES (...)
```

Please correct me if i misunderstood the question.

Comment: sounds about right.  sys.columns seems like interesting idea. I'll research it. thank

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do without the data loss.
1) you can use Insert statement

```
  `
    Insert into EmpNew (ID,fname,lname)
        Select e_id, e_fname, e_lastname 
            from EmpOld
  `
```

2) You can simple use Import-Export Wizard
     Go to Start Menu > SQL Server 2008/2008R2/2012 > ImportandExport> 
   This will take you the wizard box

- Select Source :- DataSource(ServerName) and Database where you are
      extracting data from

  - Select Destination :  DataSource(ServerName) and Database where you are extracting data to
  - Map the table
  - BE AWARE of PK/FK/Identity

you are good to go